# VS Code - JavaScript HTML DOM - autocomplete/suggestion of class and id names are not working

Tags: javascript, html, class, autocomplete, ids

In VS Code, there is a limitation where the autocomplete or suggestion feature for JavaScript class and ID names does not function as expected, unlike the seamless support provided for HTML and CSS. I feel functionality is absent when referencing class and ID names directly in JavaScript. This absence makes us to manually recall and type the correct class and ID names, leading to potential errors and slower coding workflows. I'm pretty new to this, so any help would be great! Thanks!

I tried several extensions, but no go. Please specify if there is any working extension to achieve this.